# Is there a way to download and use historical price data from Amazon?

Tags: data-request, historical, prices

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction of if/how I can obtain historical price data (ie. how much a product, say a specific CD, sold for) for Amazon or similarly for eBay, etc.

I think this would be a neat project for me to learn.

Comment: Aside from this question asking about Ebay, which the other doesn't, the questions do appear to overlap...